# Set home-activity to default

Tags: android, adb, oculus

I changed my home-activity to a custom application so that whenever the device starts, this application will be opened (Kiosk). Now I would like to reset this so that the default home-activity will be opened. How do I do this?

First I disable the VRShell which is the home-activity

```
adb shell pm disable-user com.oculus.vrshell
```

Then I set the home-activity to a custom

```
adb shell cmd package set-home-activity packageName/activityName
```

I have tried to reset to default activity this way

```
adb shell cmd package set-home-activity com.oculus.vrshell/com.oculus.vrshell.MainActivity
```

but I get `Error: Failed to set default home`

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Comment: Were you able to change the default launcher?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is because you have disabled com.oculus.vrshell.

To re enable

`adb shell pm enable com.oculus.vrshell`

Then reset the default home activty

```
adb shell cmd package set-home-activity com.oculus.vrshell/com.oculus.vrshell.MainActivity
```